# Cannot show texture in OpenGL 4.3 using VertexArrayObject

Tags: c, opengl, texture2d

I'm knocking my head on this code since two days ago. It seems that there's no error of any sort creating buffers or textures, but the texture doesn't show.

Here is my code for the texture load:

```
struct image2d texImage = loadBMPImage(filePath);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glGenTextures(1, &(result.external->texID));
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, result.external->texID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, texImage.width, texImage.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texImage.pixels);
free(texImage.pixels);
```

The image2d structure is this one

```
struct image2d{
    unsigned int width, height;
    unsigned char* pixels;
};
```

Yes, I'm enabling GL_TEXTURE_2D via glEnable()

Then my mesh is drawn wiith this code

```
void MeshDraw(Mesh m, int renderType)
{
    glBindVertexArray(m.external->vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m.external->vbo);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VERTEX_SIZE*4, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VERTEX_SIZE*4, (void*)12);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m.external->ibo);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m.external->sizeFc * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    return;
}
```

And finally here is my vertex shader

```
#version 430 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 inTexCoord;

uniform mat4 transform;

out vec2 texCoord;
out vec3 outPos;

void main(void)
{
    outPos = position;
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(position, 1.0);
    texCoord = inTexCoord;
}
```

And here is my fragment shader

```
#version 430 core

out vec4 drawColor;

in vec2 texCoord;
in vec3 outPos;

uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main(void)
{
    drawColor = texture(sampler, texCoord);
    //drawColor = vec4(clamp(outPos, 0.0, 1.0), 1.0);
}
```

If you need to look at the whole project I'm posting it [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/o0izzmq8lb63i5r/Pizza+Engine_0.1_Correzioni.zip)

I'll appreciate any kind of help :)

---

Additional code (which is also in download if anyone wants to see it)

```
void initOpenGL()
{
    printf("OpenGL version: %s\n",glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);
    return;
}
```

This is called right after making the context and initializing glew.

```
void RenderGame(Game g)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    ShaderBind(g.external->sh);
    setUniformmat4(g.external->sh, "transform", TransformGetProjectedTransformation(g.external->transf));
    TextureBind(g.external->texture);
    MeshDraw(g.external->msh, GL_TRIANGLES);
    glFlush();
    glfwSwapBuffers(WindowGetHandler(g.external->window));
    return;
}
```

And this is my render method.

Comment: try to add `glBindTexture` into the  `MeshDraw` function

Comment: I'm doing that right before the MeshDraw() call

Comment: Where are the calls for binding the program, looking up the sampler uniform into the program and setting it to the right texture unit? (Also: `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` is an error in the core profile) (Also: the whole point of VAOs is remember the vertex array setup, so it's pointless to redo the setup in all MeshDraw calls)

Comment: You're right about the VAO, I'll fix it later, but it shouldn't be the problem. As i experienced before there were no strict need to set the sampler uniform, although it could bring unexpected results even if the default sampler is 0. Even when I use it there is no texture on the geometry. What about the glEnable? Why is it an error? What should I write instead of it?
PS: You were right about the VAO, I've fixed and now the code is as it should be, but the texture still doesn't show up :/

Comment: Have you checked whether the uv-coordinates are correct? E.g. by displaying them instead of the texture's color?

Comment: Yes, the coordinates are correctly displayed as colors, but no texture at all :/

Comment: What surprises me is that if I set like `draw_Color = vec4(clamp(outPos, 0.0, 1.0), 1.0) * texture(sampler, texCoord);` there is nothing on the screen.

Comment: It seems that @peppe was right all the time. Just to be meticulous i set the sampler to 0 with the setuniform call and it worket. The problem is that it didn't work as expected.
This is the result [link](http://www.mediafire.com/view/6ox97p72cagrg20/TexResult.png)
But the image was an 8x8 checker. What could be the problem now?

Comment: Nevermind, it was the function that loads the bitmap file that was wrong. Now it works like a charm :) Thank you guys!

Comment: If you've found a solution, please either accept an existing answer or answer your own question. Please do not edit the solution into the question.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Done. Now there is my answer with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION It seems that @peppe was right all the time. Just to be meticulous i set the sampler to 0 with the setuniform call and it workef. The problem is that it didn't work as expected, and it was because the function that loads the bitmap file that was wrong. Now it works like a charm :) Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Your texture is not mipmap-complete, but you are still using the default `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` minification filter, so sampling the texture will fail.

You try to set it to `GL_NEAREST`, but this sqeuence of operations is wrong:

```
glGenTextures(1, &(result.external->texID));
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, result.external->texID);
```

In the GL, the texture sampler state is part of the texture object itself (there are also separate [sampler objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object) available nowadays which override that state, but you don't seem to use them either), and `glTexParameteri()` affects the *currently bound texture object* at the time of the call. I don't know if some texture is bound at that time, or none at all - but certainly, the new texture is not, so it will stick with the inital default of `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`...

Comment: I've changed the code to bind the texture before setting the parameters, still no texture on the object.